# Computation of integral involving Heaviside function

Tags: calculus, integration, distribution-theory

Let $H : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ denote the Heaviside function:

$$
 H(y) =
 \begin{cases}
 0 & y < 0, \\
 1 & y \ge 0.
 \end{cases}
 $$

> Suppose that $c > 1$ is fixed with $t$ ranging over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that:
>   $$
>  \int_0^\infty H(t + (1- \frac{1}{c})y - 1)H(t - \frac{y}{c})dy =
>  \begin{cases}
>  0 & t < \frac{c}{2c-1}, \\
>  \frac{c}{c-1}((2c-1)t-c) & \frac{c}{2c-1} \le t \le 1, \\
> ct & t > 1.
>  \end{cases}
>  $$

This integral appears in a research paper (on inverse problems) that I've been studying. I've been trying to work out all the cases for awhile.

The case $t >1$ is easy enough to work out. In that situation, $t + (1 - \frac{1}{c})y - 1 > (1 - \frac{1}{c})y \ge 0$, all $y \ge 0$. And $t - \frac{y}{c} \ge 0 \iff y \le ct$ Hence, $H(t + (1- \frac{1}{c})y - 1)H(t - \frac{y}{c})$ = 1 for $y \in [0,ct]$ and $0$ otherwise (this gives the correct answer for $t > 1$).

With the other cases, my main stumbling point is determining why the function should behave differently as we cross $t = \frac{c}{2c-1}$.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any more information? What I got is $0\ (t\lt 1/c)$, $c(t-1)/(c-1)$$\ (1/c\le t\le 1)$, $ct\ (t\gt 1).$ So far, I can't find any mistakes in my try.

Comment: I agree with your answer (@MoonKnight got the same one too). For completeness sake, here is a link to the paper: http://iopscience.iop.org/0266-5611/29/6/065001/
This problem appears on page 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you get the result but it seems wrong to me.

$H(..)H(..)\neq 0$ requires

1. $t-y/c\ge 0 \Rightarrow y \le ct$
2. $t+(1-1/c)y-1\ge 0 \Rightarrow y\ge c(1-t)/(c-1)$

If $1\ge t\ge 1/c$, then $0\le c(1-t)/(c-1)\le ct$. then the integral gives 
$$
\int_0^\infty H(...)H(...)dy = ct-c\frac{1-t}{c-1}=\frac{c}{c-1}(ct-1)
$$

If $t\le 1/c$, then $c(1-t)/(c-1)\ge ct$, thus $\forall y\ge0 ,H(..)H(...)=0$. So the integral gives 0.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the published answer seems to be wrong, I guess. This solution you have written is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> \begin{align}
> ? &\equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm H}\pars{t + \bracks{1- {1 \over c}}y - 1}
> {\rm H}\pars{t - {y \over c}}\,\dd y
> =
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm H}\pars{{c\bracks{1 - t} \over c - 1} - y}{\rm H}\pars{ct - y}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm H}\pars{\min\braces{ct,{c\bracks{1 - t} \over c -1}} - y}\,\dd y
> \end{align}

1. $\ds{ct < {c\pars{1 - t} \over c - 1}\quad\imp\quad
                c^{2}t - ct < c - ct\quad\imp\quad t < {1 \over c}}$
       $$
   ? = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm H}\pars{ct - y}\,\dd y
     = {\rm H}\pars{t}\int_{0}^{ct}\dd y = {\rm H}\pars{t}ct
   $$
2. $\ds{t > {1 \over c}}$
       $$
   ? = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm H}\pars{{c\bracks{1 - t} \over c - 1} - y}\,\dd y
     = {\rm H}\pars{1 - t}\int_{0}^{c\pars{1 - t}/\pars{c - 1}}\,\dd y
     = {\rm H}\pars{1 - t}\,{c\pars{1 - t} \over c - 1}
   $$

> $$
> ?=\left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{lcl}
> 0 & \mbox{if} & t < 0\ \wedge\ t > 1
> \\
> ct & \mbox{if} & 0 \leq t < {1 \over c}
> \\
> {c \over c - 1}\,\pars{1 - t} & \mbox{if} &  {1 \over c} \leq t < 1
> \end{array}\right.
> $$